# R How can I change values ending with 30?

Tags: r, data-science

How can I change the values ending with 30?

```
id  term
1  200110
2  200130
3  200230
4  200430
```

to:

```
id  term
1  200110
2  200210
3  200310
4  200510
```

Comment: what does this have to with "data-science" ... ?

Answer (score 3):

```
df$term = ifelse(df$term%%100==30,term-20,term)
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be easiest to do as a string operation.

```
term <- as.character(term)
term <- gsub("30$","10",term)
term <- as.numeric(term)
```

"30$" in the second line stands for "30 followed by the end of a line".

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `substr`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[substr(term, nchar(term)-1, nchar(term)) == 30, term := term - 20L]
df1
#   id   term
#1:  1 200110
#2:  2 200110
#3:  3 200210
#4:  4 200410
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 1:4, term = c(200110L, 200130L, 200230L, 
200430L)), .Names = c("id", "term"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```